# Polar plot in Python looks quite strange

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, polar-coordinates

with a long piece of Python code I have obtained two arrays: phi (which contains 0,1,2,...,360) and F.

If I plot F vs phi in a cartesian plot, with simply these two instructions:

```
plt.plot(phi,F)
plt.show()
```

I get the following graph.

[image]

However, if I try to plot it in a polar graph with the following piece of code:

```
plt.polar(phi,F)
plt.show()
```

I get the following graph.

[image]

The last one is not what I was expecting. I'm expecting something like a noisy circumference, since the cartesian plot of F vs phi shows a noisy behaviour with a mean value at -0.8.

I was expecting to get something **similar** (with different values since it refers to other variables) to this graph:
[image]

UPDATE1: As suggested by @luuk, I've converted `phi` from degrees to radians. Now I get this result.

[image]

UPDATE2: After changing the rlims (set from -2 to 0.1), the picture looks like this

[image]

It's still strange since there is a filled circle inside the graph. Do you know how can I remove it (if it's simply due to too dense lines)?

UPDATE 3:

If I plot it with points (`'.i'` in plot) I get a reasonable plot. But, if possible, I'd prefer to get a plot with lines.

[image]

Comment: Note that the y values in the cartesian plot have a range that crosses 0. The polar plot you are seeing can be expected. Maybe you meant to lowpass-filter the values so that they are not 0.8+-1.0 but maybe 0.8+-0.1

Comment: Thank you for this advice. I've seen there was a mistake in my graphs. Now I've updated them correctly

Comment: Although the plots now look differently, the issue is still the same.

Comment: The cartesian plot oscillates from -1.6 to 0. Why shouldn't I see an oscillating circumference in a polar plot?

Comment: You do see an oscillating circumference - with a radius between -1.6 and 0.

Comment: But why does it appear like a colour filled circle at the centre? Shouldn't be it just a circumference?

Comment: Because the lines are so dense that they are filling all pixels in the middle of the graph.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226908/discussion-between-kinka-byo-and-mkrieger1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the [Polar Demo](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/polar_demo.html), `plt.polar()` expects the `theta` argument to be in radians (with domain [0, 2π]), not in degrees. Convert `phi` to radians by multiplying by `np.pi/180`.